# What Forum Template do I modify to display Smileys?

Tags: forum

I am working through the tangled web that is the EE Forum templates in search of the correct template for adding a link to the emoticons (smileys). So far I am coming up empty handed. Anyone with experience out there that can point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the underwhelming response, I was forced to dig deeper and finally found the template I was looking for. It is:

> form_submission / submission_form